# Knockout.js 3.1.0 delivered by aspnet ajax CDN with HTTPS is not gzipped

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-ajax, gzip, cdn

I am encountering a strange issue when getting Knockout.js version 3.1.0 through aspnet ajax CDN :
The delivered file does not seem to be gzipped.

In fact, when I request the file through HTTPS :

https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.1.0.js

the delivered file is not gzipped.
The response has a `Content-Length` of 47302 bytes and no `Content-Encoding` header

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:public,max-age=31536000
Content-Length:47302
Content-Type:application/x-javascript
.
.
Server:ECAcc (ory/42A3)
```

whereas when I request the file through HTTP, I get a `Content-Length` of 21861 bytes, and a `Content-Encoding` header with value 'gzip'

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.1.0.js

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:public,max-age=31536000
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:21861
Content-Type:application/x-javascript
.
.
Server:ECAcc (ory/4295)
```

It's worth mentionning that I do not encounter this issue with other versions (2.1.0 and 3.0.0) of knockout through the CDN (headers are the same on http and https.)

Did I miss something obvious ? Anyone encountering the same issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I tried it just now and got this:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:public,max-age=31536000
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length: 21861
...
Server:ECAcc (rhv/8146)
```